# How can I create activerecord models that are subsets of a certain model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

I've seen this before but can't figure out what the correct term is.  Basically, I'd like to create models for a specific subset of table data.  E.g. (these are not the real classes)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

class Man < Person
  <something here> :gender => 'male'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a single table inheritance, than I am fairly certain that this is the correct syntax. Just don't forget to define the `type` field in the table.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Man < Person 
end
```

Edit: Removed the

Comment: Wait -- what is the <something here> part?  I can't find that.

Comment: I copied it from your example.